# Magento 2 : How to remove and change My Account Navigation

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to remove some tabs and change the navigations title : 
[image]

As you can see above navigation How to remove some navigation and change the title ? For example removing `Address Book` change `NewsLetter Subscriptons` to Subscription

I was looking for the css file `nav items` and found this :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/** @var $block \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links */
?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation */ ?>
<div class="block account-nav">
    <div class="title">
        <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Account'); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <nav class="account-nav">
            <ul class="nav items">
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

From here I was looking for the `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links` but kinda stuck and have no idea what to do.

I'm new to magento 2 so kinda noob here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**1 )** Add below code in your **extended default.xml** file to **remove Account tabs** links.

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Here is list of code to remove account tabs as needed. Will helpful to you and other users as well

```
        <!-- Address link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>


        <!-- Downloadable product link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Subscription link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Billing agreement link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Product review link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- My credit card link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Account link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Account edit link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" remove="true"/>


        <!-- Orders link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Wish list link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
```

**2 )** **Renaming Newsletter  Subscriptions**

Copy customer_account.xml from

```
vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml
```

To your extended module

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Newsletter/layout/customer_account.xml
```

Let me know if any problem.

Keep cache disable while changing any XML file

Comment: thanks for your help, but how do you get all thos name ?  like `customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link`

Comment: vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml here you can find these links  , other link can be found in there simultaneous modules...like wish list in vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2 and I have to say that is not true, that file has none of the names you listed above.

Comment: @DustinPoissant  if not present then you need to create those files,,copy from vendor to you custom theme

Comment: @ManojDeswal, How to remove dashboard page and set order history page as default?

Comment: You just want single order history page, no other option ?

Answer (score 2):

Create xml file in your custom theme `app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

For Changing newsletter subscriptions to subscriptions, copy file `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml` in your custom theme `app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/Magento_Newsletter/layout/customer_account.xml` and change the required text.

Then run commands for static content deploy and cache flush.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Invitation Link from Dashboard Sections.

```
<!-- Invitations -->
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-magento-invitation-link-container" remove="true"/>
```

Remove Additional Sidebar from My account (Dashboard)

```
<!-- Additional Sidebar -->
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
```