# Remove sidebar on My Account page

Tags: magento2, php, sidebar

I want to remove some list on the sidebar in `My Account` page like in picture below. How can i do it?

**Sidebar :**

[image]

Comment: check this link. it will help you out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91648/how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation-magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```