# Customer account navigation link | Where to find referenceBlock names

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, navigation

I want to remove some links in the customer account side navigation section on my **Magento ver. 2.1.8** store.

So, I have created a path in my custom theme:

`app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`

My customer_account.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Removing the link -->
        <referenceBlock name="block-name" remove="true"/>    
    </body>
</page>
```

I found few threads and tutorials online such as: [How to add/remove links on my account navigation magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91648/how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation-magento2)

However, I don't think all the links are included in those tutorials. How can I find out what is the name of this `referenceBlock` so I can remove it?

This i my customer account navigation section:
[image]

I need to remove:

- My Downloadable products
- Stored payment methods
- Billing agreements
- My Saved cards
- My Recurring profiles

I am sure the **downloadable products**, **billing agreement** and **my saved cards** can be deleted using:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
```

But how do I delete the **Stored Payment Methods** and **My Recurring profiles** links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below code in this file

**app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**run php bin/magento cache:clean command**

**run php bin/magento cache:flush command**

**Here is the reference link for all the blocks** - https://gist.github.com/matt-bailey/3a5b36186a599b8653bb3b05115ecd90

Comment: The question asks how to delete the `Stored Payment Method`s and `My Recurring profiles` links, do you know how can I find the reference for it?

Comment: Referance name `customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link` is responsible for those two links?

Comment: Yes correct -  customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link is responsible for Stored Payment Methods and above code will removed that

Comment: It wasn't me down-voting. What is responsible for **My Saved cards** and for **My Recurring profiles** links?

Comment: @BareFeet - Here is the reference link for all the blocks - https://gist.github.com/matt-bailey/3a5b36186a599b8653bb3b05115ecd90

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add this code to the custom_account.xml file located at:

`app/design/frontend/**YourWebsite**/**NameOfYourTheme**/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>

</page>
```

I think this will remove the links as you have requested.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
You should also clean your cache and redeploy your static-content. This should make the changes appear. If not, try deleting your browser cache. Caching issues are normally the problem.