# Customer account navigation link removal is not working

Tags: magento2, customer-account, navigation

I want to remove some of the navigation links in my account page so I have put the below code at the path:

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" design_abstraction="custom">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

However, its not working. I have also tried in the core file, /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml. But still no luck. I have cleaned the cache and run all the commands.

It's working in local but having issue in the server. Is it something related to DB. If yes, where could be the issue?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your code seems correct.. on server which mode you are using ?if using production mode, need to deploy content as well...

Comment: I have ran the deploy command as well.

Comment: Also it's in developer mode only

Comment: please check after removing your browser cach and run setup and delpoy command.

Comment: @Msquare does it require run setup ? deploy command in developer ?

Comment: yes run some time it's required and check and update me

Comment: @Msquare, I have run all the deploy commands. But the link is not removing.

Comment: @Siva try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91648/how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation-magento2